# Dynamic Database Switch - Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

I want to switch my codeigniter multiple database on runtime. My Default database will run thoroughly the page but when I needed to switch to other database based on scenario or requirement then I can do. The **common model function** will work for the all different databases. ***So, I want to use same model and same function for multiple database connection using dynamic selector without using session or without passing function variable***

To achieve this I set a name in cofig and when I call my model I set the required database name in controller before calling model and then I tried to get the name in model which is set in controller. But unfortunately I'm not getting the name from controller to model.

Database Configuration File -

```
$db['default'] = array(
               'dsn'    => '',
               'hostname' => 'localhost',
               'username' => 'root',
               'password' => 'pass'
               'database' => 'db1'
                .......
               );


$db['anotherDB'] = array(
               'dsn'    => '',
               'hostname' => 'localhost',
               'username' => 'root',
               'password' => 'pass'
               'database' => 'db2'
                .......
               );
```

Controller -

```
$this->config->set_item('active_db', 'anotherDB');
$sql = 'select * from user';
$anotherDB_record = $this->model->customQuery($sql);

print_r($anotherDB_record);


$this->config->set_item('active_db', 'default');
$sql = 'select * from customer';
$default_record = $this->model->customQuery($sql);

print_r($default_record);
```

Mode -

```
   protected $database;
   function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
       $oDB = $this->config->item('active_db');
       $this->database = $this->load->database($oDB, TRUE);
   }    
   function customQuery($sql){
       $query = $this->database->query( $sql );
       return $query->result();
   }
```

This is the way I have tried to switch my database. If you guys have any other best solution to switch multiple database then please feel free to suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

Try bellow example for dynamically configure another database

common model

```
function getOtherDB($groupID) {
    $getRecord = $this->common_model->getRow('group_master', 'GroupID', $groupID);
    if ($getRecord) {
        $config['database'] = $getRecord->DBName;
        $config['hostname'] = $getRecord->DBHostIP;
        $config['username'] = $getRecord->DBHostUName;
        $config['password'] = $getRecord->DBHostPassw;
        $config['dbdriver'] = "mysqli";
        $config['dbprefix'] = "";
        $config['pconnect'] = FALSE;
        $config['db_debug'] = TRUE;
        $DB2 = $this->load->database($config, TRUE);
        if ($DB2) {
            return $DB2;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

In the above example, I have group_master table which has group wise database details by passing GroupId I fetch the record and set Another database according to group **Make sure your all database configuration information stored in the database is encrypted format** Use below example to fire query on Other database

```
$result = $DB2->query("select * from group");
// $DB2 is other database instance you can create multiple db connection using above methos
```