# CodeIgniter: Change default database connection on the fly

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

After a user logs in, database credentials are gathered from database.

I need to change database connection to use this credentials on following queries.

I found I can do:

```
$dsn = 'dbdriver://username:password@hostname/database';
$this->load->database($dsn);
```

But I am not sure how to do this change in one place and that it applies to next queries and discard config on database.

Any ideas?

Comment: please refer this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53043800/dynamic-database-switch-codeigniter/53044169#53044169

Comment: you can use multiple DB instace, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8269596/6309457

Comment: @DevsiOdedra In my case database connection is dynamic.

Comment: @Sachin interesting example, but how can I make that connection default one over all the application without modifying all the places where load->database is called?

Comment: so you can use as `$dsn3 = 'mysql://user:password@localhost/db3';
$this->db3= $this->load->database($dsn3, true);  $this->db3->insert('tablename', $insert_array);`

Comment: @Eduardo try this 
// close the default connection
$this->db->close();
// connect to the other db
$this->db = $this->load->database($config, TRUE);

Comment: @Sachin I think that might work!, I will keep you posted!

Answer (score 0):

First you need declare the 2nd parameter in `load->database` and create a instance db like this:

```
$db = $this->load->database($dsn,true);
```

Then you can use $db from execute some Query like this

```
$db->query("Your SQL Code is here");
```

You can put that code in a local function inside some model or controller class to resolve your needs

Answer (score 0):

I usually create model class in codeigniter and define a property called $dbsecond and in construction I assign database to this property

```
class PanelDb extends CI_Model
{
public $dbsecond;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->dbsecond=$this->load->database('panel', TRUE);
}
}

public function insertData(){
$this->dbsecond->insert(.....);
}
```

and to use this database in every part of controller I load this class in construction

```
class Monitor extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model('login','model');
    $this->load->model('PanelDb ','panelmodel');
}
}
```

Then in controller I use

```
$this->panelmodel->insertData(......)
```